# Excel error copied array not updating

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, copy-paste

I'm working with a 2m cell excel table in Excel 2007. I am using a VBA macro too:

`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBSTITUTE(CONCATENATE(RC[-4],RC[-1]),"" "","""")"`

For a while everything worked fine, I have pressed the assigned shortcut key, the array was there, then I clicked and pulled and all data validated in the cells where I dragged this. 
Then it stopped.

Now what it does is to paste the formula, WITH THE RESULT OF THE FIRST CELL and containing the CORRECT array, with the correct line number. As I press f2 the array appears and updates itself for enter. OK, but I cannot do this for 5500 lines, and it worked well before. 
Did I press a wrong key, or did something in VBA that changed the paste attributes? What could have gone wrong?

Comment: This line of the code does paste anything? Is this the whole code? This line only applies a formula to one cell?

Comment: Sub Makró3()
'
' Makró3 Makró
'
' Billentyűparancs: Ctrl+k
'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBSTITUTE(CONCATENATE(RC[-4],RC[-1]),"" "","""")"
    
End Sub
 That is the whole script. I guess this has something to do with excel paste settings, because this applies to all worksheets but not in other excel files ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. In formulas menu there is an icon, counting settings, that was modified from automatic to manual. No idea, how. Anyway it works fine now. :)